An overview of my circom circuit?
I wonder if there is a way that I can know how many components there are and the constraints each component has in my circuit. It shall form a tree structure as:
x: 100  (main component)
├── x1: 40
│   ├── x1-1: 5
│   ├── x1-2: 20
│   └── x1-3: 15
└── x2: 60
    ├── x2-1: 40
    └── x2-2: 20

